# How to avoid duplication of add_header directives in nginx?

Tags: nginx, http-headers

The documentation says this:

> These directives are inherited from the previous level if and only if there are no add_header directives defined on the current level.

My problem is that I have several `location` blocks that I want to cache, like this one:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";

location ~ ^/img/(.*)\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp)$ {
    expires 1w;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

But that will make me lose all the headers declared outside of the block. So apparently the only way is duplicating those headers on every location block, eg:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";

location ~ ^/img/(.*)\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp)$ {
    expires 1w;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
}
```

Doesn't seem right. Any ideas?

Comment: or split your config up into different files and include as appropriate.

Comment: @AD7six You mean a file just for the headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're after the ngx_headers_more module: 
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/headers_more/

And yes, the behaviour of add_header is really irritating :)

Comment: I was using that module for vanity purposes (changing the name of the server), but I didn't want to rely on it for serious things. Ok I guess I'll have to use it if there is no other way. Thanks.